# Photoshop Scripting with Applescript -- will not open images without a prompt

Tags: pdf, automation, applescript, photoshop

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5.1"
set myFile to (choose file) as string
open file myFile
end tell
```

This results in 2 separate dialogs opening asking me what file to open.... It doesn't matter what I select first, it asks a second time and opens the second.

What I want to open is a PDF, so I really want:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5.1"
set myFile to (choose file) as string
open file myFile as PDF with options {class:PDF open options, mode:CMYK, resolution:300, use antialias:true, page:1} showing dialogs never
end tell
```

Result:

```
Error: General Photoshop error occurred. This functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop
```

All right a more direct approach:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5.1"
set myFilePath to alias "other: PREPRESS SAVE:GAMES:3Sudoku:20120213pzsud-v:sudoku 0213.pdf"
with timeout of 300 seconds
        open myFilePath as PDF with options {class:PDF open options, mode:CMYK, resolution:300, use antialias:true, page:1} 
end timeout
end tell
```

The file exists or the setting of the alias would fail. So what do I get?

```
 "Error: -43. Adobe Photoshop CS5.1 got an error: File some object wasn’t found."
```

[I had asked over on the Adobe forums, with no response.](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4186126#4186126) The full code I'm really trying to use is there if you're interested. I reduced it to basics to figure out what the problem is.

Is there a setting somewhere that I am missing? I'm not sure what is wrong, the example out of the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are horrible issues with The Photoshop 5 dictionary. One idea is to try and run it in 32-bit mode which 'solves' a lot of issues. Please digest further in http://forums.adobe.com/message/2822670#2822670?tstart=0#2822670

Comment: I was able to find something there I will give a try                                                                                                                                                                                                  set theImage to (choose file with prompt "Please select an image file:") as string  --This is from StandardAdditions of AppleScript Dictionary
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5"
   open alias theImage --"open file theImage" should work (w/o quote), too.
end tell

Answer (score 1):

Might be a CS5 issue, but I honestly don't know.

This worked fine for me, but with CS4:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS4"
    set myFile to (choose file) as alias
    with timeout of 300 seconds
        open myFile as PDF with options {class:PDF open options, mode:CMYK, resolution:300, use antialias:true, page:1}
    end timeout
end tell
```

The only real difference (that I can see) is that I `alias` the chosen file, and call `open ...` - not `open file ...`

Comment: This does work in CS4, perhaps that is the real solution. In CS5 this results in:     "Error: -43. Adobe Photoshop CS5.1 got an error: File some object wasn’t found."